# JPEG DCT changed after sending from WP 8.1 EmailMessage?

Tags: c#, jpeg, windows-phone-8.1, steganography, dct

I am working on steganography DCT-based method on Windows Phone 8.1.
I was really happy that there is finally a API for sending emails with attachments which was missing in Windows Phone 7 - 8. I started to create a method for sending emails with JPEG images and I am stuck on the following.

I created stagnographic JPEG image which has modified DCT coefficient and I would like to send the image through email.

So I am using the following example from MSDN pages:

```
private async void ComposeEmail(Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.Contact recipient, 
    string messageBody, 
    StorageFile attachmentFile)
{
    var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
    emailMessage.Body = messageBody;

    if (attachmentFile != null)
    {
        var stream = Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(attachmentFile);

        var attachment = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailAttachment(
            attachmentFile.Name,
            stream);

        emailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);
    }

    var email = recipient.Emails.FirstOrDefault<Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactEmail>();
    if (email != null)
    {
        var emailRecipient = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient(email.Address);
        emailMessage.To.Add(emailRecipient);
    }

    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);

}
```

JPEG image is sent but it seems that it was recompressed because DCT coefficients are changed. I can't figure out if DCT coefficients are changed after reading the file from local app storage as RandomAccessStreamReference or by the Email API of Windows Phone 8.1 itslef.

But there is definitely something that is modifying JPEG somehow.

Is there any workaround how to send original JPEG image? Maybe there is a way how to send original bytes of JPEG image without using RandomAccessStreamReference?

Comment: If there is no way to prevent recompression during transmission, you need to consider (and tell us) the following. Which algorithm you used (provide paper reference if possible) and how robust it is to image recompression. You can test this after creating a jpeg stego image and verify that you can extract your data. Resave that image with different quality factors and see when the message is destroyed. There isn't much point sticking with an algorithm that isn't suitable to the situation.

Comment: It looks like you've encountered one of the many frustrating features of WP that MS won't change. They don't seem to allow email attachments without recompressing them as their own JPEGs (even if not needed) and they don't let you use "reserved" mime types for your apps. Both policies are anti-consumer and don't "protect" the user from anything harmful.

Comment: I implemented F5 algorithm [http://www2.htw-dresden.de/~westfeld/publikationen/21370289.pdf](http://www2.htw-dresden.de/~westfeld/publikationen/21370289.pdf) and it is not resistant to JPEG compression so if there is no way how to send JPEG images through API in WP 8.1 without recompression then F5 is useless for that purpose. Do you know about some steganographic algorithm that is robust and could survive recompression like this in WP 8.1?